# peewee migration "has no column named FOREIGN"

Tags: sqlite, peewee

I'm trying to use peewee's migration module to rename a column from `name` to `title` in my `page` table. However I'm running this confusing error:

```
peewee.OperationalError: table page__tmp__ has no column named FOREIGN
```

My guess is that it has something to do with the need to create an intermediary table when using sqlite.

---

**Current Model:**

Full source is here https://github.com/csytan/textmug/blob/master/db.py

```
class User(BaseModel):
    id = peewee.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=20)

class Page(BaseModel):
    id = peewee.PrimaryKeyField()
    name = peewee.TextField(unique=True, null=True)
    user = peewee.ForeignKeyField(User, null=True, related_name='pages')
```

**Migration Script:**

```
from playhouse import migrate

my_db = migrate.SqliteDatabase('database')
migrator = migrate.SqliteMigrator(my_db)

with my_db.transaction():
    migrate.migrate(
        migrator.rename_column('page', 'name', 'title')
    )
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in the migrator code... I'll take a look, thanks! https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/issues/380

Comment: This bug has been fixed, in case anyone wanders across this.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it manually with the sqlite3 command line tool:

```
BEGIN;

ALTER TABLE "page" RENAME TO "page_tmp";

CREATE TABLE "page" ("id" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "title" TEXT, "user_id" TEXT, "created" DATETIME NOT NULL, "text" TEXT NOT NULL, "public" SMALLINT NOT NULL, "encrypted" SMALLINT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY ("user_id") REFERENCES "user" ("id"));

INSERT INTO "page" SELECT "id","name","user_id","created","text","public","encrypted" FROM "page_tmp";

DROP TABLE "page_tmp";

COMMIT;
```